# Flyway - JDBC query

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, flyway, data-migration, redgate

Do I have to install the JDBC driver to use flyway with PostgreSQL?
If YES - then which JDBC - do I have to download?

I am completely new to data migration - need to know which JDBC I have to install?

Comment: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

Comment: PostgreSQL JDBC 4.2 Driver, 42.3.1

I have downloaded the file. 
Where shall I relocate the file?
In Flyway ->  C:\Program Files\Flyway
or in PostgreSQL  -> C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14


or do I have to set path for somethng

Answer (score 0):

Currently the PostgreSql 42.2.19 JDBC driver comes as part of Flyway.
If you are using the command line app, you can see this under the drivers folder, where you can also override it with a later JDBC.